# Convert a call using (arg1, arg2, success, error) into a Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using a third party library that exposes functions of the form function(arg1, arg2, successFunction, errorFunction).

To prevent my code from nesting success functions levels deep, I would like to use Promise.all

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Promise wrapper to your third library:

```
function Promise_wrapper(arg1, arg2){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
        yourLib(arg1, arg2, function(result){
            resolve(result)
        }, function(error){
            reject(error)
        })
  });
}
```

obiouvsly now you can call `Promise.all()` with an array of `Promise_wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise like below:

```js
function yourMethodReturningPromise(arg1, arg2) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    yourFunctionUsingCallback(arg1, arg2, (something) => resolve(something), () => reject("errors")).  
  });
}
```

The you can use yourMethodReturningPromise like below:

```js
yourMethodReturningPromise(arg1, arg2).then((res) => {
    console.log("success: ", res);
}, (err) => console.log("errors"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple: [Use the `Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) and just pass `resolve` as the successFunction callback and `reject` as the errorFunction callback:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    libraryFunction(arg1, arg2, resolve, reject);
});
```

You might want to wrap this in a helper function that takes only `arg1` and `arg2` as parameters and returns the promise.